# JRadioButton calling options

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

This is the code:

```
  String male = "Male";
  String female = "Female";

 JRadioButton checkGenderMale = new JRadioButton(male);
      checkGenderMale.addActionListener(new genderListener());

JRadioButton checkGenderFemale = new JRadioButton(female);
      checkGenderMale.addActionListener(new genderListener());

class genderListener implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       System.out.println( );
   }
}
```

In the line System.out.println(); I would like the option (the Strings male or female which ever is selected) to print. So what might go in the parenthesis?

Comment: use ItemListener for JRadioButton / JCheckBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write

```
AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton) actionEvent.getSource();
System.out.println("Selected: " + aButton.getText());
```

In your action performed method.

Comment: When I put that in, actionEvent is underlined red. Would you explain briefly what the first line is accomplishing?

Comment: The first line is just getting on which component the event has occurred, in above it is getting occurred on RadioButton, thing is ActionListener is generic for many UI components in JAVA, but there are also Generic classes such as AbstractButton, we can get source of event and then use that source we can get its properties.

Comment: Thank you so much! Will this work to get the selected items from a JComboBox as well?

Comment: It is because you have done a small mistake by adding genderListener on same "checkGenderMale". change second "checkGenderMale.addActionListener(new genderListener());" to "checkGenderFemale.addActionListener(new genderListener());"

Comment: also if you want to achieve one JRadioButton should get selected you need to add following code where you have added your JRadioButtons,  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(checkGenderMale);
group.add(checkGenderFemale);

Comment: @Maydayfluffy for JComboBox you need to add ItemListener, please have a look at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/combobox_CbItemEvt.html it is easy to understand

Comment: It says the page is not available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8852/discussion-between-rahul-borkar-and-maydayfluffy)

Comment: you can also check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html